# TensorFlow weight initialization taking 99% of total run time

Tags: performance, optimization, tensorflow, profiling, gpu

#### Problem

I noticed that one of my networks was running slow and nvidia-smi was reporting only around ~10% GPU usage. After running the profiler, I saw that `TruncatedNormal` process was taking the vast majority of running time (see photo). What could causing this kind of problem?

[image: TensorFlow profiler]

#### Code

Weight declaration function (from MNIST tutorial):

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
```

Code in action:

```
 # First Layer
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, Nvars])
    w1 = weight_variable([Nvars, 8])
    b1 = bias_variable([8])
    y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the tensorflow functions that you are using have multiplicative properties. When a CPU needs to invoke the product handler, performance degrades exponentially.

The problem may be avoided if the calculation is pre-supported by the kernel. What you need to do is use compiler optimization; i.e. change some compiler settings which will cause the compiler to 'ease' the multiplication.

Or... you could just not multiply, and just add a few times.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Do you mean that tf.truncated_normal() has multiplicative properties?